# Add halo to image when hover

Tags: html, css, hover, shadow, halo

First time posting. I have the following shortcode in my stylesheet for creating images in circles

```
.make-circle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%; 

}
```

If I want to add a 'halo' shadow on hover how would I go about adding this in here? I was thinking about making a new class and then adding it to the img tag but I think this would clash with the above shortcode? This is the code for referencing the above:

```
<img class="make-circle" src="#">
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: as long as you don't have a border-radius property in the new class, the classes' properties will add and not overwrite each other

Comment: Ah excellent thanks! Thought one may overwrite the other but makes sense that it would only be if they had conflicting statements. Bloody part timers like me!!